# How to know that a batch file that was called within java code has finished executing?

Tags: java

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start C:/Users/Desktop/Batch.bat");
```

I am running a batch file from within java that executes a database query to write a large volume of data into a file, it takes few minutes to execute. I need to present a "loading" dialog to the user that prompts him when the file generated from above is ready to use. The process starting command prompt exist immediately.So is there is any way to keep track when will the command prompt process will get over ?

Answer (score 2):

`Runtime.exec(..)` returns a [`Process`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html) object that offers several methods:

- [`waitFor()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#waitFor--) to block until the process is finished
- [`isAlive()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#isAlive--) to periodically check whether the process is still running

Comment: Process exist After starting cmd only .So we need to keep track when cmd exit.

Comment: @Anuj that should still work since the process should represent the cmd you start.

Comment: Nops its not working as soon as the cmd start the process.isAlive() return false.I think The process which started cmd get over and a cmd process is itself running

Comment: Hmm in that case it seems that the batch process itself is detached and cmd isn't waiting for it. Hence even `waitFor()` should return immediately. If so you'd probably have to change your command, i.e. either directly execute the batch file or pass some other parameter to cmd (might be `/K` instead of `/C`).

Comment: I can pass exit to command prompt to terminate it as soon as it finish.But how should i keep track of it in java?

Comment: @Anuj as I said, `isAlive()` or `waitFor()` should work if you do that. I'm also not sure whether passing "exit" instead of just changing the parameter is a good idea but that's up to you. If the aforementioned methods don't work you might have to use the process' output (e.g. via its InputStream) and periodically check that.

Comment: I get it waitFor() will work only when i will add \wait in the Runtime param .Thanks Thomas

Answer (score 0):

`Runtime.getRuntime().exec()` retuns an object of type `Process` which has the method `waitFor()`.

This secret information is taken from the Oracle API:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec(java.lang.String)

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#waitFor()